# make text bigger than containing box - css

Tags: css, xhtml, positioning

Im trying to get a text to appear as though it is too big for the containing box that it is in.

It is a bit hard to describe so here is a picture i made.

[image]

I want to try to get around making images for them, but i could if its not possible with css.

I have a scenario setup with jsfiddle, even though there isnt any js involved. Its a useful tool :]

http://jsfiddle.net/Lv2EE/

I tried to do some fancy positioning where the `<span>` tag would be positioned under the `<h4>` but that didnt work because the H4 collapses when i did that.

any ideas?

Comment: i see now thanks, so the only real properties that matter are line-height and overflow:hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative, using a container div to clip the child header element: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv2EE/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="clip"><h4>Sidebar</h4></div>
```

CSS:

```
h4 { 
position : relative; 
top : -30px; 
background-color : #345678; 
color : white; 
font-size : 4.5em; 
overflow : hidden; }

.clip { 
display : block; 
height : 30px; 
overflow : hidden; 
}
```

This should work properly across browsers; I included the 'display : block' so it could work with `<span>` as well.

Comment: ya this is how i intially wanted to do it, i think i might have to test out both versions. I do want a solution that works across more browsers.

Comment: You could even use some Jquery to sandwich all h4's of a certain class with their corresponding div.clip...

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/qg7VZ/)

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<h4>Hello</h4>
```

**CSS:**

```
h4 {
    background-color:#00a2e8;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:5em;
    line-height:0.6em;
    padding:0 0 2px 0;
    font-weight:bold;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:#99d9ea
}
```

Comment: I think you need to clip the bottom as well.

Comment: @Phrogz: I thought my demo already looked like the example image. If it doesn't (for you), what browser/etc are you using?

Comment: I'm guessing that happens because Arial and Helvetica are slightly different. With a bit of fiddling of the numbers, it's probably possible to get it to look adequate with both fonts.

Comment: @phrogz i see whats happening in the picture but i cant browser test on osx. adjusting the line-height accordingly will probably help the effect

Comment: Removing the 2px padding helps a little on OS X. No amount of changing the line-height affects the baseline relative to the bottom of the box. The simplest fix is to wrap `<h4><span>...</span></h4>` and then `h4 span { position:relative; top:0.2em }`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/7hmfJ/10/